# jQuery validate from link

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm working with a CMS product which slightly confines how I can set out a form in the backend. Therefore I have essentially the following (simple example):

```
<form>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="box1" />
    <input type="button" id="submit1" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="box2" />
    <input type="button" id="submit2" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="box3" />
    <input type="button" id="submit3" />
</div>
</form>
```

I want to use jQuery validate, however what I need it to do is to validate box1 when submit1 is clicked, box2 when submit2 is clicked and so on.

Is  this possible?

Thanks
Al

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using 3 forms since you have 3 buttons that you are wanting use for submits?

Answer (score 2):

split them into different forms and validate them one by one when user click different **submit** buttons:

```
<form name="form1" id="form1">
<div>
    <input type="text" id="box1" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit1" />
</div>
</form>
<form name="form2" id="form2">
<div>
    <input type="text" id="box2" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit2" />
</div>
</form>
```

don't forget to accept suitable answers, this will increase the willingness for others to provide answer.